# Is it possible to create a UIDatePicker with the format YYYY-MM-DD in iOS in English?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, uidatepicker

I'm trying to implement a `UIDatePicker` that allows a user to select a date of birth. This would be relatively straightforward, but there's also a requirement that the user be over 18. This isn't a problem (`UIDatePicker` has a `minimumDate` property that allows me to specify that), but it does present a usability issue.

If you select the date, lets say for example, May 4th. With the locale set to en_GB, this will appear as May 4th 2014. Lets assume for the moment that this date is after today. Before you get a chance to change the year to, lets say, 1977, the date picker will force the date back to today.

I'd like to solve this by changing the display format to YYYY-MM-DD without having to implement a `UIPickerView` (a solution that may require a fair amount of work to implement properly). Is there a way to do this with `UIDatePicker` that allows the same enforcement of date while having better usability? Preferably I'd like to do this without a custom class either (and obviously private APIs are out to - can't risk rejection from the App Store). Alternatively, is there a better way of implementing a date of birth picker?

Comment: don't set `minimumDate` and validate the birthday in code instead?

Comment: @MatthiasBauch: That's probably the approach I'd have to take but its not ideal. I'd like the picker itself to simply not allow users to choose a date that's pre-18, but the way the picker itself is implemented seems too harsh. It'd be ideal to increase the time when it scrolls back to the valid range but that just doesn't seem doable ...

Answer (score 0):

you want to switch the order of columns of the picker:

no this isn't doable right away.

maybe you can find some locale that has the Y/M/D format

Comment: US Locale specifies MM DD YYYY - which isn't going to work either unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see without creating a custom picker is using

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView  *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

You can check if user is on a valid selection, if not you can force the picker to stay on a valid position. Saying that every time user scrolls one of the rows you should perform a validation check, instead of setting min and max date for your `datePicker`

Comment: That's got the same kind of usability issue - it would force the user to try setting each of the month and day fields before getting to the year field to have a chance of success. Might be a slight improvement, but its still not quite as elegant as I'd like ...

Comment: not if you make your own validation and check which year should correspond to this date and moth to make user be over 18 and then set this year in your years row